# How to program without type safety

Tags: python, type-safety

Java is a **hard typed** language, and exchanging to Python I fell a little hard to get along with no type safety.
So, can any one help me good practices and concepts to program without type safety.

- Do I need to verify on every getter and setter if the value `isinstance` of the desired type?
- How would I use POO without type safety?
- How I can encapsulate my objects without type safety?

Comment: Just...let go... *be free...*

Comment: generally no. in python its sorta understood that you dont shove square pegs into round holes.

Comment: If you want to clutter your code with a bazillion `isinstance` calls go ahead, but doing so is very non-pythonic. Python is [duck-typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), and that is on purpose!

Comment: Simply.. in python, type is defined by it's interface, not what it is. You can use completely different implementation with the same methods and it should work.

Comment: @MightyPork but, how is this possible without checking every possible type?

Comment: @FabioBohnenberger: You dont. As long as you clearly documented the interface you expected, it's the caller's duty to pass in something sensible, and if he dont, well he gets a nice traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you should not type check usually. let types free. Forget about type-safety. All code in python are a kind of generic programming.
- Object-oriented programming is not combined with type safety.
- Python doesn't support encapsulation of instance variable or private function. But sensible pythonista uses `_` prefix for private variable or function.

Instead, unit-testing will help you.
In my favorite, `nosetests` and `watchdog` are great tools.
`nosetest` runs all `*_test.py` files in your project.
`watchmedo` in `watchdog` will watch file change and does specific command.

usually I use these two tools like

```
$ watchmedo shell-command --patterns="*.py" --recursive --wait --command="nosetest -sv"
```

This one-liner runs unit-test automatically every update in *.py file.
All your code modification will be monitored.